# Dropped row in df bringing 'keyerror' with the row index in future loops. Row not properly dropped?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing, keyerror

With my df, I dropped index 3116:

```
df=df.drop(df.index[3116],axis=0)
```

However, when I try to use a for loop with the rows in the df later, there's an error at 3116. Not sure why? Is it not dropped correctly? Because when I use df.info(), there is 1 less column so I would think it's correct but later there's an error:

```
for i in range(df['ever_married'].count()):
  if df['ever_married'][i] == 'Yes':
    df['ever_married'][i]=1
  elif df['ever_married'][i] =='No':
    df['ever_married'][i]=0
```

This brings:

```
'KeyError: 3116'
```

However, when I add to before the first if block in the for loop:

```
if i==3116:
    pass
```

The error goes away, but the code doesn't perform how I want by converting all values from obj to int.

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I highly recommend iterating over the row indices, i.e. `for i in df.index:`. That way, in the event of skipped indices (like 3116), the dataframe indexing doesn't get tripped up.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the index at that position, then the dataframe has a non-contiguous index. Later, when you loop over it, you make the assumption that the index is contiguous:

```py
for i in range(df['ever_married'].count()):
```

This will loop from 0 to the number of rows in your database, and does not skip any dropped rows. There are four fixes you could choose from here:

1. Get rid of the loop. [Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) could be applied to this problem, like so:

   ```py
   df['ever_married'] = df['ever_married'].map({'No': 0, 'Yes': 1})
   ```

   This is both faster and more robust. It replaces No with 0, and Yes with 1, everywhere in the column.
2. Index using `.iloc[]` instead of indexes. The `.iloc[]` indexer selects by position within the series or dataframe, rather than by index.

   Example of how to set the value in column "ever_married" at index i to 1.

   ```py
   df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('ever_married')]=1
   ```
3. Restore a contiguous index using `.reset_index()`. [DataFrame.reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) can reset the index so that it is contiguous and does not skip any numbers.

   Example:

   ```py
   df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
   ```
4. Use `for i in df.index:` to skip over missing rows.

Of the four solutions, I would suggest solution 1.